# ExifInterface.TagOrientation returns 0 (ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED)

Tags: android, android-emulator, xamarin.android

When working with a picture taken by the MediaStore.ActionImageCapture intent using the Visual Studio Emulator, the following code return 0 (ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED)

```
ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(fileName);
return exif.GetAttribute(ExifInterface.TagOrientation);
```

From what I can see by displaying the file in an ImageView , the value I should get would be 6 (ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90).
Working with a real device gives me 6.
I'm not confident to write some code to do the rotation if the value is undefined, which is why I’m trying to understand why I’m getting ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED and not ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90.

Is there any known bug in the emulator? What should I do to handle this?